# ADF popup resize

Tags: popup, oracle-adf, popupwindow

I'm using a popup in my ADF page, and some of the text is out of the popup window. How can I resize it? Here's my code:

```
<af:popup childCreation="deferred"
    autoCancel="disabled" id="p2"
    binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.p2}">
<af:dialog id="d2"
           binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.d2}"
           title="Confirmação"
           type="cancel">
    <f:facet name="buttonBar">
        <af:commandButton text="Gravar"
                          id="cb6"
                          binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.cb6}"
                          action="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.checkRadioButtonAndPerformSave}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl45"
                        binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.pgl45}">
        <af:gridRow marginTop="5px"
                    height="auto"
                    id="gr20"
                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.gr20}">
            <af:gridCell marginStart="5px"
                         width="5mm"
                         id="gc104"
                         binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.gc104}">
                <af:selectOneRadio label=""
                                   id="sor1"
                                   binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.sor1}"
                                   autoSubmit="true">
                    <af:selectItem label="Os níveis abaixo herdarem tudo o que alterou;"
                                   value="radio1"
                                   id="si55"
                                   binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si55}"/>
                    <af:selectItem label="Os níveis abaixo herdarem tudo o que alterou menos as exceções que tenham já definidas, caso existam."
                                   value="radio2"
                                   id="si56"
                                   binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.si56}"/>
                </af:selectOneRadio>
            </af:gridCell>
            <af:gridCell marginStart="5px"
                         marginEnd="5px"
                         width="50%"
                         id="gc115"
                         binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.gc115}">
                <af:outputText id="ot1"
                               binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.ot1}"/>
            </af:gridCell>
        </af:gridRow>
        <af:gridRow marginTop="5px"
                    marginBottom="5px"
                    height="auto"
                    id="gr23"
                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.gr23}">
            <af:gridCell marginStart="5px"
                         width="50%"
                         id="gc116"
                         binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.gc116}"/>
            <af:gridCell marginStart="5px"
                         marginEnd="5px"
                         width="50%"
                         id="gc117"
                         binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.gc117}">
                <af:outputText id="ot2"
                               binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Setup.ot2}"/>
            </af:gridCell>
        </af:gridRow>
    </af:panelGridLayout>
</af:dialog>
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either try to set explicit dimensions for `af:dialog` control or try to wrap or even replace current `panelGridLayout` with set of `panelGroupLayout`.
In fact if I got your idea right, you can use simple `panelFormLayout` to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can solve this in different ways
1> try with surrounding  your panel grid layout with a panel form layout
2> instead giving your label for your  select one radio you can use separate input text component for displaying label and you can wrap it.
3>you can set dimensions for your dialog explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Use panelGrouplayout instead of panel grid, also use the style class AFStretchWidth in panel group lay out to stretch within the pop-up.
Another component panel window will be more useful that its size can be adjusted in run time.